# R sqlQuery function (in robdc package) regards character variable as numeric variable

Tags: r, rodbc, qsqlquery

```
> my_query <- paste("select * from", query_table, "where Arrived_Date_Time >=", arrived_earliest_date, "and Arrived_Date_Time < ", arrived_latest_date)
> dfDataIn <- sqlQuery(NSSP, my_query, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> odbcCloseAll()

> table(dfDataIn$Discharge_Disposition)

    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    20    21 
64059   336  1522    32   306  1166  2343     1 35423   312    36 
   30    41    43    50    51    61    62    63    64    65    66 
   26    18   295   133   200     5   270    76     3  1121   811 
   70   100 
  249    24
```

Actually `dfDataIn$Discharge_Disposition` is a character variable, and most importantly, most `1` here are supposed to be `"01"` in the database, whereas only minority are truly `"1"` in the database. (similarly for `2`-`9`)

Is there any way to read the data in the right format?

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using? And, what is the result of `getSqlTypeInfo()'?

Answer (score 1):

You could try as.is = TRUE.

dfDataIn <- sqlQuery(NSSP, my_query, as.is = TRUE)

This will bring the data as is from the data source.